# Please explain npx limitation - Unable to use assertion library while running npx mocha

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js, npx

Tl;dr:
`npx -p chai -p mocha mocha test.js` yields Error: Cannot find module 'chai'

Question: I can't use chai here? Because..?...It's not executable?

Context:

I thought a nice use of npx would be to write example tests and code together in one file and run those tests (seems ideal for letting people get their hands on tdd without worrying too much about the surrounding ecosystem.)

This mocha example works great:

```
// addOne/test.js
const assert = require('assert')

function addOne(num){
  return isNaN(num) ? 'not a number' : num+1
}


describe('addOne', function() {

  it('returns a number increased by a value of 1' , function(){
    assert.equal(addOne(0), 1)
    assert.equal(addOne(-1), 0)
    assert.equal(addOne(.1), 1.1)
  })

  it('returns the message "not a number" if given a non-number value', function(){
     assert.equal(addOne('foo'), 'not a number')
     assert.equal(addOne(function(){return 2}), 'not a number')
  })

})
```

(In root of directory addOne run `npx mocha test.js`)

HOWEVER
what if I wanted to use an expectation library, like chai's 'expect'?

```
var chai = require('chai')
var expect = chai.expect

< function >

describe('addOne', function() {

  it('returns a number increased by a value of 1' , function(){
    expect(addOne(0)).to.equal(1)

< etc >
```

Knowing I can install multiple packages with npx I have tried running

`npx -p chai -p mocha mocha test.js`

but get:  `Error: Cannot find module 'chai'`

Have I hit a limitation of npx? Must all packages you provide it be executable?